# SD card is not mounted in Lubuntu

Tags: 12.10, lubuntu, sd-card, camera

I have a 2 GB Transcend SD card for my camera, but when I entered it in my laptop's SD slot then it was not mounted automatically by Lubuntu. I did not have the same problem with Ubuntu. I can not see it either in the graphical Storage Device Manager.

I tried the following workarounds on the bugs mentioned in [1](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/872093/comments/28) and [2](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/872093/comments/50), but the problem still persists.

Kernel Version: 3.5.0-25-generic

OK, I tried `dmesg` and here are the steps:

**`dmesg` output**:

```
[ 9219.520160] mmc0: Timeout waiting for hardware interrupt.
[ 9229.536177] mmc0: Timeout waiting for hardware interrupt.
[ 9239.552162] mmc0: Timeout waiting for hardware interrupt.
[ 9243.048896] mmc0: Card removed during transfer!
[ 9243.048908] mmc0: Resetting controller
```

**`lspci` output**:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Mobile 945GM/PM/GMS, 943/940GML and 945GT Express Memory Controller Hub (rev 03)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Mobile 945GM/GMS, 943/940GML Express Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 03)
00:02.1 Display controller: Intel Corporation Mobile 945GM/GMS/GME, 943/940GML Express Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 03)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 02)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family PCI Express Port 1 (rev 02)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family PCI Express Port 2 (rev 02)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family PCI Express Port 3 (rev 02)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family USB UHCI Controller #1 (rev 02)
00:1d.1 USB controller: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family USB UHCI Controller #2 (rev 02)
00:1d.2 USB controller: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family USB UHCI Controller #3 (rev 02)
00:1d.3 USB controller: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family USB UHCI Controller #4 (rev 02)
00:1d.7 USB controller: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family USB2 EHCI Controller (rev 02)
00:1e.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801 Mobile PCI Bridge (rev e2)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation 82801GBM (ICH7-M) LPC Interface Bridge (rev 02)
00:1f.1 IDE interface: Intel Corporation 82801G (ICH7 Family) IDE Controller (rev 02)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 82801GBM/GHM (ICH7-M Family) SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 02)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family SMBus Controller (rev 02)
05:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation PRO/Wireless 3945ABG [Golan] Network Connection (rev 02)
06:04.0 FireWire (IEEE 1394): O2 Micro, Inc. Firewire (IEEE 1394) (rev 02)
06:04.2 SD Host controller: O2 Micro, Inc. Integrated MMC/SD Controller (rev 01)
06:04.3 Mass storage controller: O2 Micro, Inc. Integrated MS/xD Controller (rev 01)
06:05.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL-8139/8139C/8139C+ (rev 10)
```

How can I resolve this issue?

I also tried it with Linux Mint (Linux version 3.5.0-17-generic) in my laptop, and it still does not work...

Comment: Have you tried another card? This looks like a bad card like I've had in the past.

Comment: It looks like the storage card is broken (more likely), the card reader is broken (less likely) or the card reader driver is buggy (also less likely). I recommend that you try different cards in the same card reader and the same card in a different card reader.

Answer (score 1):

MountManager is described as "The program for mounting of storage devices, flash cards, removable disks in Linux". Even if it doesn't solve your problem completely, MountManager will make it easier for you to mount and unmount your SD card manually. MountManager is no longer available from the default Ubuntu repositories for versions of Ubuntu newer than Ubuntu 12.10 and instead you can use the Disks application which is installed by default in Ubuntu.

You can take a look at a screenshot of mountmanager by searching for it in Synaptic Package Manager and clicking on "Get Screenshot", and you can also install it from Synaptic.

Comment: The Mountmanager does not show the SD card as well.

Comment: This program worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you're experiencing the same issue as me, but this gets it to automount on my laptop:

```
sudo -i
echo 1 > /sys/bus/pci/rescan
exit
```

Comment: could you please explain whats the above code will do , Thank you My Friend.

Comment: This does not work as well...

Comment: It issues a PCI slot rescan

Answer (score -1):

First check if really not mounted:

```
mount  -l
```

If not, try to mount it manually:
http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man8/mount.8.html shows you how to do this. Looks complicated, but is pretty simple after you have done it once.

Comment: I am not quite sure how to do this...

There is also another problem. I can connect my Camera with USB anyway but for some reasons I can not copy large video files. When I start copying large files from my Camera to Laptop through USB (the USB is connected to the Camera) then the copy fails because after some time the device seems unmounted. Do you know why is that so? It works fine with image files or small video files.

Comment: Well, maybe a dumb question here, did it work with Windows/Mac OS X before? Else I would say it is an implementation fail by the camera . Had same problem with my HD Camcorder, both Ubuntu and Windows and couldn't fix it...

Comment: Yes, it worked with Windows and Ubuntu before but it does not work with Lubuntu anymore

Comment: strange, sorry no clue then...